# Return C# Object to PowerShell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, active-directory

I need to script a PowerShell script which is cleaning some AD groups. As I know it is possible to implement C# code into a PowerShell script and it's also possible to use PowerShell objects in C# code but in the different way?

I want to write a small script in C# which is retrieving the "real" User object of the group, because of some migration processes there are some duplicates and I need to detect the "real" one.

So, is it possible to retrieve C# objects in PowerShell and working with it? I only can find solutions in the different way.

Best regards

Comment: How are you attempting to detect the "real" object? PowerShell is quite powerful (hence its name), and there is little that I have found that I need to do with AD that requires using C#, VBScript, or other non-Powershell tools.

Comment: I don't understand your question : most items I get as a result in Powershell is either a PSOBJECT or a .Net object (and a PSOBJECT is of course also a .net object).

Comment: There's no difference between an object in C# and an object in PowerShell. Both C# and PowerShell work with .NET objects, and objects can be freely passed between the two systems.